# Why is the gcloud sdk's deploy command looking at my home directory for files?

Tags: gcloud

I'm attempting to deploy a python server to Google App Engine.

I'm trying to use the `gcloud` sdk to do so.

It appears the command I need to use is `gcloud app deploy`.

I get the following error:

```
me@mymachine:~/development/some-app/backend$ gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The directory [~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cache] has too many files (greater than 1000).
```

I had to add `~/.config` to my `.gcloudignore` to get past this error.

Why was it looking there at all?

[The full repo of my project is public](https://github.com/komali2/game-remix-guesser) but I believe I've included the relevant portion.

Comment: You could add `--verbosity=debug` to get more detailed logging from the command. Is there anything "unusual" about `./backend`? Does the same issue occur if you use a vanilla hello-world example and try to deploy that. Perhaps be more explicit and `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`. What's in app.yaml?

Comment: It should not, of course, need to check `~/.config/google-chrome` unless, somehow, that's being instructed. The error would then result because there is an upload limit on the number of files in a deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I looked at your linked repo and **there aren't** any `yaml` files.  As far as I know, a GAE project needs an `app.yaml` file because that file tells GAE what your runtime is so that GAE knows how to deploy/run your code. In fact, according to the [gcloud app deploy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy), if you don't specify any `yaml` files to be deployed, it will default to `app.yaml` in the current directory. If it can't find any in the current directory, it will try to build one.
2. Your repo also shows you have a Dockerfile. [GAE documentation for custom runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) says  ...*Custom runtimes let you build apps that run in an environment defined by a Dockerfile*... In the `app.yaml` file for custom runtimes, you will have the following entry

```
   runtime: custom
   env: flex
```

3. Since you don't have an `app.yaml` file and you have a Docker file in which you are downloading and installing `Chrome`, it seems to me that `gcloud app deploy` is trying to infer your runtime and this has led to it executing some or all of the contents of the Dockerfile before it attempts to then push it to Production. This is what is making it take a peek at the config file on your local machine till you explicitly tell it to ignore it. To be clear, I'm not 100% sure of this, just trying to see if I can draw a logical conclusion.

My suggestion would be to create an app.yaml file and specify a custom runtime. Or just use the python runtime with flex

Comment: That appears to be exactly correct, and this was very helpful as I wasn't sure if I could even use my Dockerfile if deploying on gcloud, which was frustrating as I need chrome so the app can render sites, so you helped me twice over by pointing out how I can set up the gcloud app environment to my liking!